# Ansible object list from merging a list and a value

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

Given a string list

```
list:
  - a
  - b
```

and a string

```
str: c
```

How can be obtained an object list with the same number of elements as the first list with the following structure?:

```
new_list:
  - list_key: a
    str_key: c
  - list_key: b
    str_key: c
```

Also, I'm using Ansible 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new_list: "{{ list|
                      map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '{list_key: \\1}')|
                      map('from_yaml')|
                      map('combine', {'str_key': str})|
                      list }}"
```